# Datatype Mismatch on New Columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone know why my code is giving this error even though my return types should match?

The only thing I can think of is that the datatype of `reserved_seats` and `cancelled_seats` are not of type `INTEGER` despite `NumSeats` column being of type `INTEGER` (where it gets the data).

If anyone can give any advice I would appreciate it.

The error that occurs is:

```
ERROR: "return type mismatch in function declared to return record"
```

My create statement:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seatInformation(INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE(flightID INTEGER, reserved_seats 
    INTEGER, cancelled_seats INTEGER, available_Seats INTEGER, MaxCapacity bigint) AS
    $$
      SELECT f.flightID, (SELECT reserved_seats FROM (SELECT fb.NumSeats WHERE fb.Status = 'r') AS reserved_seats), 
      (SELECT cancelled_seats FROM(SELECT fb.NumSeats WHERE fb.Status = 'c') AS cancelled_seats), MaxCapacity - SUM(fb.NumSeats) AS Available_Seats, f.MaxCapacity
      FROM Flight f INNER JOIN FlightBooking fb
      ON f.flightID = fb.flightID
      WHERE f.flightID = $1
      GROUP BY f.flightID, fb.NumSeats, fb.Status;
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;

    CREATE TABLE Flight 
(
    FlightID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FlightDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    Origin VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Destination VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    MaxCapacity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PricePerSeat DECIMAL NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Flight_pk PRIMARY KEY(FlightID)
);


CREATE TABLE FlightBooking 
(
    BookingID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FlightBooking_fkc REFERENCES LeadCustomer(CustomerID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FlightID INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FlightBooking_fkf REFERENCES Flight(FlightID) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    NumSeats INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    BookingTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    TotalCost DECIMAL,
    CONSTRAINT FlightBooking_pk PRIMARY KEY(BookingID)
);
```

Many thanks,
Callum

Comment: Please provide your tables' description to have a clear picture of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
(SELECT reserved_seats FROM (SELECT fb.NumSeats WHERE fb.Status = 'r') AS reserved_seats)
```

You may think it is integer, well, it's not.  It selects a set.

This is what you may want instead:

```
(SELECT fb.NumSeats as reserved_seats WHERE fb.Status = 'r' LIMIT 1)
```

The same for `cancelled_seats`

Comment: Still giving the same error, I guess I need to change my `RETURNS TABLE` data types for reserved_seats/cancelled_seats to something else?